# List the 3 most common land use types per level group by architectural style (SQL)

Tags: sql

I run into difficulties with a question, and because I am a beginner in SQL I failed to solve that. I have two Excel. The first one contains information about historical buildings in a city with different building styles. Each building might have several floors and each floor might have several uses. These uses have different codes. The second excel list these codes with their description. I need to list the 3 most common land use types per level group by an architectural style. I have tried several methods, but I failed to solve the question. I show you a photo of each Excel here.

To solve the question, I have made 2 tables and entered my information and then, I separated my floors with this code:

```
create view floors as (
select building_number as building_number, building_style as building_style,
code_use1_cellar as code_use1_cellar, code_use2_cellar as code_use2_cellar, 
code_use1_g_floor as code_use1_g_floor, code_use2_g_floor as code_use2_g_floor,
code_use3_g_floor as code_use3_g_floor, code_use4_g_floor as code_use4_g_floor, 
code_use5_g_floor as code_use5_g_floor, code_use1_1_floor as code_use1_1_floor, 
code_use2_1_floor as code_use2_1_floor, code_use3_1_floor as code_use3_1_floor, 
code_use4_1_floor as code_use4_1_floor, code_use1_2_floor as code_use1_2_floor,
code_use1_3_floor as code_use1_3_floor, code_use1_4_floor as code_use1_4_floor
from useland
```

For floors with just one use, it is easy to list the 3 most uses based on different styles. I used these codes for the forth floor for example:

```
create view test4 as(
select building_style, code_use1_4_floor as code, count(code_use1_4_floor) as codenumber
from floors
group by building_style, code_use1_4_floor
order by building_style, count(code_use1_4_floor) desc 
)
create view final_test4 as (
select t4.building_style, t4.code, luc.description
from test4 t4
inner join land_use_code luc
on luc.code=t4.code
order by building_style
)
```

My results for the fourth floor:

[results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KgnJM.png)

My main difficulty is that some floors have several uses (different columns instead of just one column) and I cannot count values of separate columns and enter the results in just one column. If I have just one column for all uses and then, one column for the number of their codes for each floor, like the fourth floor, I can solve the problem, I guess.

[image: useland]

[image: usecode]

Comment: Please tag your DBMS, and show us what you have done so far with text data rather than images by editing the question, not as comments.

Comment: What code  do you mean? What's the current attempt even if as a starting SQL?

Comment: I understand that columns D and H, in the first Excel spreadsheet, reference column A in the second Excel spreadsheet. Is that correct?

Comment: @ Barbaros Ozhan I have tried to edit my question and entered my codes and the result for one floor as an example. Honestly, this is the first time I am using Stack Overflow, and sorry for my faults.

Comment: @Abra You are right. Columns D, F, and H contain codes that can be found in the second excel with a comment.

Comment: Build a database with normalized data structure. A UNION query can rearrange columns to normalized dataset. Then use that query as source for subsequent queries analyzing data.